# 404 monitor - "/cgi-sys/suspendedpage.cgi"

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I have a 404 monitor on my Wordpress website and it seems to have a lot of traffic going to the following url:

https://themonk.com.au/cgi-sys/suspendedpage.cgi

What is "suspendedpage.cgi", why has this occurred, and what should I do about it? Should I add a redirect to the home page and not worry about it?

Comment: It's typically a cPanel page when your account is/was suspended.